# 'Вспомнить' и 'припомнить'

Tags: значения

Кажется, понимаю значение 'вспомнить.' Я бы охарактеризовать это как мгновенное воспоминание или "to recall" на английском. Но я не знаю как отличать это от глагола 'припомнить.' Они кажутся очень похожими. Как они отличаются друг от друга в определении и исполнении?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь приставка "при-" имеет значение неполноты действия (чуть-чуть). То есть "вспомнить" - это чёткий образ в памяти, а "припомнить" - смутный, неуверенный, на грани забывания.

Comment: Заметьте, что значение смутного, неуверенного воспоминания проявляется у глагола "припомнить" в несовершенном виде сильнее, чем в совершенном. В совершенном виде "припомнить" гораздо чаще имеет значение угрозы, о котором написал @Dmitry

Answer (score 5):

Есть еще такое значение у *припомнить*:
*Припомнить кому-либо что-либо* - означает угрозу/предупреждение в адрес *кого-либо*, что его поступок не будет забыт.
Например:

> Я тебе это еще припомню!

или

> Она ему это еще припомнит.